# Toggle autoplay attribute on HTML5 videos

Tags: jquery, prop

I have some overlays on my website containing HTML5 videos. By default the overlays are not visible but they can be activated with clicking on certain images.

When an overlay is inactive I’d like the HTML5 videos to be inactive too. That’s no big deal. When an overlay is active (it gets the class `active`) the containing videos should get the attribute `autostart`. When the overlay is closed again the `autostart`attribute should be removed from the videos.

```
// Check if there are videos who have a grandgrandparent with the class `.active`
if ( $( 'video' ).parents( '.active' ).length ) {

    // Now I need the videos which suit this condition but I don’t know how

    // Add autoplay attribute to all these videos
    $( videos ).prop( 'autoplay', true );

} else {

    // Remove the autoplay attribute from all videos when the parent doesn’t have the class active
    $( videos ).prop( 'autoplay', false );

}
```

Comment: try setting `attr("autoplay", true)` and `removeAttr("autoplay")`...

Comment: No, that’s not the issue … Besides the `prop` method is the right way to add or remove attributes for HTML videos.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong approach with `autostart` …

I finally came up with using `play();` and `pause();` to start an stop the animation.

```
// Pause all videos by default
$( 'video' ).each(function () {
  $( this ).trigger( 'pause' );
});

// Start videos which have a parent with the class .active
$( '.active video' ).each(function () {
  $( this ).trigger( 'play' );
});
```